# Согласование или управление, или Как подружить числительное и существительное

Tags: согласование, числительные, существительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Путаница в рассуждениях... Поясните разницу в употреблении согласования и управления числительного и существительного, читаю правило, но опять же не понимаю конечного вывода (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/61-rubric-92):

Правильно: тысяче работников, миллиону работников, трем тысячам работников (д. п.), тысячей работников, миллионом работников, тремя тысячами работников, тысячью работниками и одной тысячей работников (т. п.).
Правильно: обратиться к двадцати пяти тысячам студентов, но обратиться к двадцати пяти тысячам ста студентам. (ПОЧЕМУУУУУ - ОБЕ ЦИФРЫ ВЕДЬ КОНКРЕТНЫЕ)

Я так поняла, что нормативным является согласование во всех падежах, кроме именительного и винительного, управление также употребляется, когда тысяча  употребляется в значении "много", неопределенного количества.  Слова миллион, миллиард во всех падежах управляют существительными в родительном падеже множественного числа (миллион жителей, миллиона жителей, миллионам жителей). http://www.pf.ujep.cz/files/KBO/Nazarenko/cvicebnice_3_4/page34.html).

В тупик ставят ответы справочной службы русского языка на Грамоте:

1) «Какое окончание правильное: более восьми тысячам ветеранов (ветеранам) назначена отраслевая пенсия. Ответ справочной службы русского языка Правильно: *более восьми тысячам ветеранам...*»

2) «Правильно ли согласовано? "... позволил 50000 работникам по всему миру иметь..." 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка Должно быть: пятидесяти тысячам работников.»

3) «Прочитала статью об употреблении числительных и ответы на вопросы по ключевому слову "тысяча", но всё равно не могу понять, верна ли следующая фраза:

"...получили доступ к записям о 30 тысячах счетах, на которых хранилось...."

Я бы, не задумываясь, написала "о 30 тысячах счетов", поскольку напрашивается управление "тысяч чего?", но очень смутил ответ на вопрос № 235507. По какому именно правилу в нём корректно "квартирах", а не "квартир"?
Спасибо.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Корректно: о тридцати тысячах счетов, но о двадцати тысячах ста счетах. Ответ № 235507 исправлен».

Объясните разницу между этими случаями, пожалуйста. Откуда расхождения в ответах справочной службы?

Кроме того, нашла следующее: «Как утверждает, Д.Э. Розенталь, "во множественном числе слово тысяча, как правило, употребляется в значении счетного существительного и управляет связанным с ним словом: город с двумя тысячами жителей". Таким образом, словосочетания "ста тысячам долларов" и "пяти тысячам долларов" нельзя счесть "неправильными". В целом же хочется еще раз подчеркнуть, что особенности сочетаемости слова "тысяча" не вполне выяснены и недостаточно описаны».

Когда же выбирать управление, а когда согласование? Буду признательна не за ссылки на правила, а за объяснение своими словами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ответы**

1) Более восьми тысячам **ветеранов**, пятидесяти тысячам **работников**,  к записям о 30 тысячах **счетов**. Обычное управление Р.п. для существительного, зависимого от слова «тысяча».

2) Обратиться к двадцати пяти **тысячам студентов** (управление Р.п.)  обратиться к двадцати пяти тысячам **ста студентам**.  Во втором случае согласование по числительному «ста», а не по слову «тысячам».

**КРАТКАЯ ТЕОРИЯ**

Слова тысяча, миллион, миллиард  - это **грамматические существительные** с числовым значением.

**1)  Управление  Р. падежом существительных**

Слова тысяча, миллион, миллиард  во всех падежах управляют Р. падежом зависимых существительных: проехать тысячу **километров**, исчисляться миллионами **лет**.

**2)   На конце составного числительного находится слова тысяча, миллион, миллиард**

В этом случае  количественные числительные в И.-В. падеже  задают словам тысяча, миллион,  миллиард  Р. падеж, а в косвенных падежах  согласуются с ними (**при этом существительное в счетных оборотах используется в форме Р.п**.)

И.-В.   три тысячи деревьев, пять миллионов рублей; Р. Д. Т. П.     лесопарк пополнился тремя тысячами **деревьев**, не хватает пяти миллионов **рублей**, речь идет о трех тысячах **рублей**.

**3)    На конце составного числительного находится количественное числительное**

В этом случае **согласование делается по количественному числительному**.

И.-В.   три тысячи  сто деревьев,   Р. Д. Т. П.     лесопарк пополнился тремя тысячами  **ста деревьями**, речь идет о трех тысячах **ста рублях**.